# The negation of the statement

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My try:

1) B

2) a) at least one person is unhappy

b) There is at least one prime number between 10 million and 11 million

c) If $(pq + 1)$ is prime , then at least one of $p$ and $q$ is prime

d) At least one number of the from $2^n -1$ is not multiple of $3$ nor prime

e) All the above statements are false

[image]
Are these answers correct ? Thanks is advance

Comment: Well, $2a)$ is wrong since your unhappy person might not be rich.  $2c)$ is wrong as well.

Comment: Would you give me the right answer for them ? @lulu

Comment: I think you can manage them, those two cases are no harder than the others that you did get right.  In my comment I essentially told you how to fix $2a)$.

Comment: I know that 2a is easy but i have mistook it because i did not notice the word "rich" originally @lulu

Comment: I upvoted the question, not because I like the question, but because someone downvoted without giving a reason, and I don't see a good reason to downvote. This question seems perfectly reasonable to me. It's a question and answer site.

Comment: They are all correct (once you correct "rich") except 2c) which is very wrong.  I'm not sure how you got the others all correct but that one wrong with is not really any different than the others.

Answer (score 1):

Like lulu alluded to, 2a) and 2c) are incorrect. I'll give you some hints and the answers as spoilers.

2a) is probably an "oops" because you forgot to mention "rich":

> At least one rich person is unhappy.

The negation of 2c) relies on the fact that $\neg(p \implies q)$ is equivalent to $p \land \neg q$:

> Both $p$ and $q$ are prime, and $(pq+1)$ is not prime.